# Debug и проверка кода Android. Как ускорить этот процесс?

Tags: android, отладка

Пока учился и решал задачи на пару классов перепроверять написанное с помощью запуска кода было быстрым процессом.
Сейчас же пишу приложение под Андройд при написании даже мелкого метода или алгоритма, чтобы проверить его корректную работу приходится приложение постоянно пересобирать(gradle) и запускать на телефоне. Это сильно отнимает время, а приложение мелкое, что же будет если оно начнет расти?
Собственно вопрос кто как с этим борится? Можно как-то проверять отдельные участки кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы смотрел в сторону Unit тестирования, хотя не факт, что это даст ожидаемую скорость http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Плюс существуют достаточно быстрые эмуляторы: https://www.genymotion.com/
бесплатный для личного пользования и https://xamarin.com/android-player который тоже денег не просит пока. В некоторых случаях они гораздо быстрее телефона.

Comment: Да, спасибо я юзаю genymotio. Штука супер. Да и свой телефон иногда. Но проблема в другом в самой сборке проекта в idea

Comment: А про Unit тестирование сейчас читну. Сенкс.